# How to use ctrlp in conjunction with css and ctags

Tags: ctags, plugin-ctrlp

I've already configured ctags to index css files like documented here: [vim-tagbar-css](https://github.com/mtscout6/vim-tagbar-css)

Also tagbar already works with configuration provided at: [tagbar-css.vim](https://github.com/mtscout6/vim-tagbar-css/blob/master/plugin/tagbar-css.vim)

Still CtrlP doesn't show any tags inside of a css file in "buffer tags" mode.
Other files like PHP are working fine.

Where can I find more information to make it work, or how can I make it work?

Comment: I would start by asking on their issue tracker and reading the docs, like [this one](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L87) - those variables may be useful

Comment: Use [vim-css3-syntax](https://github.com/hail2u/vim-css3-syntax). The plugin you are using seems old and unmaintained...

Comment: Thanks @grodzik found the docs but didn't think defining own type would be necessary. Worked for me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to configure the css type for ctrlp to complete the ctags kinds, as mentioned in the docs, thanks @grodzik:

```
let g:ctrlp_buftag_types = {
\ 'css' : '--css-types=vcitm',
\ }
```

This configures to complete the ctags kinds "v", "c", "i", "t" and "m",
They are configured in ctags:

```
--langmap=css:.css.less.scss
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/@\1/v,var,variables/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/.\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/#\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,media,medias/
```

As already mentioned in the question.